# Does Facebook SDK distinguish between iOS debug vs release build

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Does Facebook distinguish between debug and release iOS builds? I am testing my app before submitting a new build to iTunes. My app uses the single permission of posting photo on Facebook (i.e. publish_actions). The strange thing is when I test with my Facebook account, it goes through fine. But when I test with my partner's Facebook account, it does not go through: The developer account is linked to my Facebook account; not my partner's. Basically for the following method

```
// Convenience method to perform some action that requires the "publish_actions" permissions.
- (void)performPublishAction:(void(^)(void))action {
    // we defer request for permission to post to the moment of post, then we check for the permission
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
        // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now
        NSLog(@"Requesting publish permission");
        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Completion handler returns for permission");
                                                NSLog(@"My Permissions are: %@",session.permissions);
                                                if (!error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Okay no error");
                                                    action();
                                                } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {                                                    NSLog(@"ERROR GETTING PERMISSION:: %@",error);
                                                }
                                            }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"the other route");
        action();
    }

}
```

`action()` is never called.

The line

```
NSLog(@"My Permissions are: %@",session.permissions);
```

prints

```
My Permissions are: (
    "public_profile"
)
```

And the line

```
 NSLog(@"The ERROR IS: %@",error);
```

prints

```
The ERROR IS: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonUserCancelled" UserInfo=0x1702779c0 
{com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonUserCancelled,
 NSLocalizedFailureReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonUserCancelled,
 com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x170169480, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler:
 0x100374240, appID: 123456789, urlSchemeSuffix: ,
 tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x17022a740>, expirationDate: 2015-05-19 19:07:02 +0000,
 refreshDate: 2015-03-20 19:07:02 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "public_profile"
)>}
```

Comment: Essentially -- at least in my opinion -- my partner's Facebook Account cannot read publish_actions permission from Facebook SDK. Also, my partner is already allowing Instagram to post. But somehow our own app is not getting the permission for his account.

Comment: Did you solve the problem

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score -1):

Nopes Facebook doesnt distinguish between debug and release iOS builds. But the thing is that you havent unable your application for general user mood. To be made login avilable for general user you have to unable your application in https://developers.facebook.com/ where you have register your applications

1. First go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and login with your developer account
2. Click on My Apps and select the application you have registered[image]

3.CLick on settings option and enter your email in Contact Email option and save changes[image]
4.Click on status & review and make it yes [image]

5. you will saw following dialogue click on confirm [image]
6. Now you will be able to login with any of the facebook account

Answer (score -1):

The SDK does not distinguish between build configurations. Has your app gone through login view : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login ?